# Unable to create a new system partition in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

I want to install Windows 7 on my partition Disk and the type of partion is :`Primary` , but when I Select the drive for installing win 7, this error will display : 
**Unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition.see the setup log files for more information.**
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: also there isn't any connected external hard on my system!

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely related to the disk being a dynamic disk. If you don't have data that you need to protect, you will need to remove all disks from your system except the one that you want to install onto. Then you will need to delete all partitions. Then install Windows onto the disk and allow it to create its own partitions and volumes. After that, connect all disks that you want on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try solution described in [this blog article](http://druss.pp.ua/2013/10/fix-error-during-installing-windows-7-from-usb-setup-was-unable-to-create-a-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-partition/) which not require any disk manipulations